# Adding a time period in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel

A simple question, but some quick Googling did not prove fruitful.

Basically, I have a column called "uniqueID", which is a unique identifier for all the people in my dataset. Most uniqueIDs have multiple records, because there is one record per year that the person stayed at university. What I'd like to do is create a "time period" variable, where first year, t= 1, second year t=2, third year t=3 etc. for each unique ID.

Comment: Please, avoid cross posting. Question was asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23179556/1578604).

Answer (score 0):

The following will work IF YOUR SPREADSHEET IS SORTED by your unique id;

=IF(A2=A1,B1+1,1)

(assumes that above formula is in column B and that data begins on row 2)

and, of course, copied down for all rows.

You will find that in a spreadsheet containing many rows, COUNTIF (suggested in your other question) is very slow since you are looking up through ever-increasing range sizes.